# Using $match to filter by dates using PHP MongoDB Aggregation Framework

Tags: php, mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

I've been trying to use the PHP MongoDB driver with the aggregation framework to filter over a few dates before piping into a $group, but the match isn't doing any filtering on dates, yet it works perfectly when filtering on strings and ints.

Here's my pipeline array and code:

> ```
>   $date = new DateTime();
>     $date->sub(new DateInterval('PT' . $hours . 'H'));
>     $mdate = new MongoDate($date->getTimestamp());
>     $ops = array(
>         array('$match') => array(
>             'whenField' => array(
>                 '$gt' => $mdate
>             )
>         )
>     );
> ```
>
> $results = $this->collection->aggregate($ops);

This should return all documents in my collection where 'whenField' is in the last 3 hours, but it returns every document in my collection. I can then switch the '$gt' to an '$lt' and it also returns every document in the collection. I've put this exact same match array as a filter and used `find($filter)` and it correctly filters. Are Date comparisons incompatible with the aggregation framework $match or have I made some kind of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$ops` is wrong here, try:

```
$ops = array(
    array('$match' => array(
        'whenField' => array(
            '$gt' => $mdate
        )
    )
);
```

Instead

Comment: ... I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!